# Can't retrieve user data form Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have the following firebase structure:

```
Users" : {
"angelbreath" : {
      "PvP_Wins" : 0,
      "PvP_scores" : 0,
      "avatar" : "https://i.imgur.com/qp9gnKE.png",
      "gender" : "Male",
      "userName" : "angelbreath",
      "user_class" : "Bard",
      "user_id" : "sC8JGw6SvMUGH4Id1HwcSf6Sl5n1"
    },
```

I'm trying to get the data of current auth user with no luck because of null exception. After many tries I have end up with this code:

```
private void showData() {
            DatabaseReference Users = database.getReference("Users");
            final Query userQuery = Users.orderByChild("user_id");
            final FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            userQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot post : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){
                        if(post.child("user_id").getValue().equals(user.getUid())){
                            Log.d("Output", "Found");
                            Log.d("Output", post.getKey().toString());

                            userClass.setText(post.child("user_class").getValue().toString());
                            userGender.setText(post.child("gender").getValue().toString());
                        }else{
                            Log.d("Output", "Failure");
                        }

                        Log.d("Output", post.child("user_id").toString());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

As i can understand because i m new to firebase, i have the right reference and i query the right way. I cant figure out why i get the exception.
Just in case i have the following check too :

```
//Checking whether a user as already Logged In
        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()==null){
            finish();
            //Starting the User Login Activity if the user is not Logged in
            startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
        }
```

So i think i have the current user and his id, so I query Users with the user id. What is wrong?

I'll appreciate any help!

EDIT error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String eu.healthydev.quizhero.Model.User.getUserName()' on a null object reference
        at eu.healthydev.quizhero.UserProfile$1.onDataChange(UserProfile.java:88)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzap.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzca.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzcd$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
```

Java:88

```
if(post.child("user_id").getValue().equals(user.getUid())){
```

User Model:

```
public class User {

    int PvP_wins, PvP_score;
    private String user_class, user_gender, userName;
    private String avatar, userid;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int pvP_wins, int pvP_score, String user_class, String user_gender, String userName, String avatar, String userid) {
        PvP_wins = pvP_wins;
        PvP_score = pvP_score;
        this.user_class = user_class;
        this.user_gender = user_gender;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.avatar = avatar;
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public int getPvP_wins() {
        return PvP_wins;
    }

    public void setPvP_wins(int pvP_wins) {
        PvP_wins = pvP_wins;
    }

    public int getPvP_score() {
        return PvP_score;
    }

    public void setPvP_score(int pvP_score) {
        PvP_score = pvP_score;
    }

    public String getUser_class() {
        return user_class;
    }

    public void setUser_class(String user_class) {
        this.user_class = user_class;
    }

    public String getUser_gender() {
        return user_gender;
    }

    public void setUser_gender(String user_gender) {
        this.user_gender = user_gender;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact stack trace you get.

Answer (score 0):

Placing a dot "." after `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` will automatically show which methods are available to get the current user data and no need for getting the data like that by Listener if you want to get `uid` only.(In this case)

**For example:**

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (firebaseUser != null) {
    String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();

    Log.d("Tag" + uid)
}
```

Also, after placing a dot, it will probably show other items in the current node to retrieve. The point is, I don't really see the reason of using Listener in here when you can retrieve those items just like above code.

Comment: I want to get the fields in Firebase Database (gender, userName, class etc). This are not in FirebaseAuth. I just want to get the data for the authenticated user.

Comment: Did you check something like this? `FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getGender();` I think firebase automatically does other stuff for getting items like that.

Comment: However, error is coming from `Model.User` which seems like the `getUsername` is empty.

Comment: Yeap i checked! I can take email , displayName, Metadata etc. Not the fiends in my database

Comment: What are this `post` output? (Check with `Log.d("tag" + post.toString());`) I guess you are not getting the right item. Like you said, you get email but in the current json, there is no email or metadata.

Comment: I think you didnt understand what i need to do. i want to get the firebase DATABASE fields that are for the current authenticated user. This means i need something like if FirebaseAuth.CurrentUser.uid.equals("user_id") give me the user details (class, gender, PvPWins, PvPScore) form DATABASE.

Comment: Yes. I get you. That's why I wanted you to check `post` because error says : `Model.User.getUserName()' on a null object reference` So, getUserName seems to be null but how about the whole retrieved data? You gotta check the `post` value first in order to check if there is a problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, that method `UserProfile.onDataChange()` has a `user` which is `NULL`.

difficult to tell more, unless having seen class `UserProfile` -  and how it is being instanced.

while you could initialize the fields differently (this would fix nothing, but prevent the `NPE`):

```
private String userName = "";
private String userid = "";
```

Comment: As you can see i have the java 88 line with the error. So there are 2 things that can be null. The firebase field ("user_id) or the current auth user.As i m checking the auth user and the code proceed, meaning that firebase user isnt null. So i guess that i get null the firebase (user_id). If this is the problem something is wrong with the query, and this is my problem!